# The correct way to sendmail() with phpmailer using a db connection

Tags: php, mysql, sendmail, phpmailer, mailing-list

I am trying to modify the phpmailer db mailer to use sendmail, would this code be correct below ?. I am trying to implement it into a website to email a clientbase of around 2-300 contacts.
Thanks :-)

```
<?php
require_once('./send/class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php     if not already loaded

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it     will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

 $body                = file_get_contents('contents.html');
 $body                = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);


$mail->SetFrom('list@mydomain.com', 'List manager');
$mail->AddReplyTo('list@mydomain.com', 'List manager');

$mail->Subject       = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

 $query  = "SELECT full_name, email, photo FROM employee WHERE id=$id";
$result = @MYSQL_QUERY($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
  $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";     // optional, comment out and test
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);
  $mail->AddAddress($row["email"], $row["full_name"]);
  $mail->AddStringAttachment($row["photo"], "YourPhoto.jpg");

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row["email"]) . ') ' .         $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br>';
  } else {
    echo "Message sent to :" . $row["full_name"] . ' (' . str_replace("@", "&#64;",     $row["email"]) . ')<br>';
}
// Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
$mail->ClearAddresses();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have an actual problem with this code?

Comment: No, I just merged the simple mailer script that uses the mail function and the db mailer that uses the smtp function and deleted the smtp part and added the sendmail part from the other script, I was just making sure my hacking around of the code was ok :-)  .

Comment: in the script it says WHERE id=$id  , do I have to define $id as I cant find any other ref to it in the script or the phpmailer.php

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but make sure this feature is supported by the hosting company.